# Enmascarar puerto 8080 en url

Tags: spring-boot, reescritura-url

Estoy haciendo una sencilla web con spring boot empaquetándola con maven. El .jar que genera lo he desplegado en una instancia de AWS.

La url se muestra con www.geaforestal.net:8080 y claro para dejarla como tiene que ser quería quitar la parte de 8080 de la url.

Para intentar dejar el puerto 80, en el fichero de configuración (aplication.properties) del proyecto he puesto lo siguiente:

```
server.port=80
```

pero a la hora de lanzarla me da el siguiente error ( que supongo que será de novato, este error es de la consola de Eclipse ) :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.7.RELEASE)

2016-07-28 17:50:15.297  INFO 745 --- [           main] io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaApp           : Starting GeaApp on sergios-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 745 (/Users/sergio/Desktop/Master/IngenieriaWeb/Practicas/ModuloIII/GeaForestal/target/classes started by sergio in /Users/sergio/Desktop/Master/IngenieriaWeb/Practicas/ModuloIII/GeaForestal)
2016-07-28 17:50:15.351  INFO 745 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67b467e9: startup date [Thu Jul 28 17:50:15 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-28 17:50:16.136  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-07-28 17:50:17.009  INFO 745 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c35f94e7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 17:50:17.035  INFO 745 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 17:50:17.046  INFO 745 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 17:50:17.053  INFO 745 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-28 17:50:17.586  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2016-07-28 17:50:17.940  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-07-28 17:50:17.942  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
2016-07-28 17:50:18.195  INFO 745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-07-28 17:50:18.195  INFO 745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2847 ms
2016-07-28 17:50:19.010  INFO 745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-28 17:50:19.016  INFO 745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 17:50:19.017  INFO 745 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-28 17:50:19.644  INFO 745 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-07-28 17:50:19.665  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2016-07-28 17:50:19.757  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-07-28 17:50:19.759  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-07-28 17:50:19.762  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-07-28 17:50:19.984  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-07-28 17:50:20.101  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-07-28 17:50:20.180  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-07-28 17:50:20.322  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-07-28 17:50:20.325  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-07-28 17:50:20.864  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67b467e9: startup date [Thu Jul 28 17:50:15 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-28 17:50:20.961  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/inicio]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.sobreNosotros()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.961  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/contacto]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.contacto()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.962  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/servicios]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.conocenos()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.962  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/nuestroEquipo]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.soluciones()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.962  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/nuestroTrabajo]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.certificados()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.962  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaController.text()
2016-07-28 17:50:20.964  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-07-28 17:50:20.964  INFO 745 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-07-28 17:50:21.009  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-28 17:50:21.009  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-28 17:50:21.067  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-07-28 17:50:21.490  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-28 17:50:21.582 ERROR 745 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]

java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaApp.main(GeaApp.java:11)

2016-07-28 17:50:21.585 ERROR 745 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaApp.main(GeaApp.java:11)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
... 13 common frames omitted

2016-07-28 17:50:21.597  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-07-28 17:50:21.611  INFO 745 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/sergio/Desktop/Master/IngenieriaWeb/Practicas/ModuloIII/GeaForestal/target/classes/, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.2.9/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.9.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.7/aspectjrt-1.8.7.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.7/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.28/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-juli-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.7.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.8.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.28/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/squareup/retrofit/retrofit/1.7.1/retrofit-1.7.1.jar, file:/Users/sergio/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar]
2016-07-28 17:50:21.611  INFO 745 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-07-28 17:50:21.611 ERROR 745 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaApp.main(GeaApp.java:11)

2016-07-28 17:50:21.612  INFO 745 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67b467e9: startup date [Thu Jul 28 17:50:15 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-28 17:50:21.614  INFO 745 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-07-28 17:50:21.620  INFO 745 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-07-28 17:50:21.621  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-07-28 17:50:21.622  INFO 745 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at io.github.web.thymeleaf.GeaApp.main(GeaApp.java:11)
```

Para el desarrollo he utilizado Eclipse Java EE IDE fro Web Developers.
Me gustaría que la url se mostrara como www.geaforestal.net ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: En primer lugar deberías generar un .war y no un .jar, por otro lado que servidor de aplicaciones estás usando?

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que tu problema es de permisos con la maquina de AWS donde estas tratando de arrancar tu jar generado con spring boot. Yo empezarÍa por comprobar que el puerto 80 no esta siendo usado por otro programa, tipicamente apache web server.

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba que el puerto 80 no esta siendo utilizado, netstat -n ayuda sirve en Windows tambien.

Es suficiente con ver que no hay ninguna direccion remota con el puerto 80 y con una IP de tu máquina antes de iniciar tu tomcat.

```
$ netstat -n

Conexiones activas

Proto  Dirección local        Dirección remota       Estado
TCP    127.0.0.1:58667        127.0.0.1:58668        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:58668        127.0.0.1:58667        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:58673        127.0.0.1:58674        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:58674        127.0.0.1:58673        ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo del OS que tenga la máquina en AWS, si es una versión reciente de Unix/Linux, simplemente no vas a tener permisos para usar el puerto 80. Es necesario configurar el OS y el usuario con el que despliegas para que esto sea posible (usar puertos bajos hasta 1024)